# Why a question/answer gets more up votes even if there's a better answer having less votes?

Tags: discussion

I have seen many question/answer getting more up votes even if there's a better answer having less votes, I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: Because maybe not everyone thinks like you about what's better? (i.e. voting is subjective)

Comment: Example? Generally votes corresponds loosely to views, so questions better ranked on Google will (over time) perform better. The answer at the top, if it works, is generally as far as people read.

Comment: My advice is to use your votes to have your say and if an answer has more votes than what you perceive as the better answer, add a comment under it to say why the other answer is better. This may lead to the user that answered improving their post and act as a message that other users viewing it to highlight any floors in the solution. Your comment, if appropriate should also gain up votes and become more visible over time.

Comment: One reason this can happen is if the better answer was posted later, when the other answer already had a lot of upvotes

Comment: You could do a search on meta for questions about voting. There is a mountain of understanding for you to be found, if you read around a little.